# Collision between a point and a square

Tags: equation-solving, geometry, discretization

Suppose we have a point of time laws:

```
xP[t_] := 0.40 + 0.51 t;
yP[t_] := 0.41 + 0.42 t;
```

and a square with side:

```
L := 2.01
```

and with center and angle of rotation of hourly laws:

```
xC[t_] := 0.50 - 0.01 t;
yC[t_] := 0.50 + 0.01 t;
θ[t_] := 0.52 + 0.01 t;
```

Defining the square as follows:

```
q = ImplicitRegion[Max[Abs[x - xC[t] + Tan[θ[t]] y], 
                       Abs[y - yC[t] - Tan[θ[t]] x]] == L/2, {x, y}];
```

at time `t = 0` the situation is as follows:

```
Show[Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{xP[0], yP[0]}]}],
     RegionPlot[DiscretizeRegion[q /. {t -> 0}]],
     PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]
```

[image]

Finally, to calculate the time `t*>0` of the first collision between the point and the square I thought of solving the following equation:

```
NSolve[Max[Abs[xP[t] - xC[t] + Tan[θ[t]] yP[t]], 
           Abs[yP[t] - yC[t] - Tan[θ[t]] xP[t]]] == L/2 , t]
```

Unfortunately neither the plot nor the equation are successful and I do not know how to solve it.

Thank you!

Comment: FindRoot[Max[Abs[xP[t] - xC[t] + Tan[\[Theta][t]] yP[t]], 
   Abs[yP[t] - yC[t] - Tan[\[Theta][t]] xP[t]]] == L/2, {t, 1}]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a function which you pass it the time, and will return `True` is point is inside the rectangle else `False`. This is based on test given in [how-to-check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-rectangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190111/how-to-check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-rectangle/190373#190373)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The implementation of the above is also given in [finding-whether-a-point-lies-inside-a-rectangle-or-not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752725/finding-whether-a-point-lies-inside-a-rectangle-or-not) which I translated to Mathematica and added a small Manipulate on top of it.

You call the function as follows

```
isPointInside[1.73]
(* true*)
isPointInside[1.74]
(* False*)
```

So point hits the edge between the above two values. Now that you have this function, you can easily find the exact `t` it changes from `True` to `False`.

[image]

Code:

```
xP[t_] := 0.40 + 0.51 t;
yP[t_] := 0.41 + 0.42 t;
xC[t_] := 0.50 - 0.01 t;
yC[t_] := 0.50 + 0.01 t;
L0 = 2.01;
angle[t_] := 0.52 + 0.01 t;

isPointInside[t_] := 
  Module[{p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y, p4x, p4y, p21, p41, p, p21Mag, p41Mag},
   {p1x, p1y} = 
    RotationTransform[angle[t], {xC[t], yC[t]}][{xC[t] - L0/2, 
      yC[t] + L0/2}];
   {p2x, p2y} = 
    RotationTransform[angle[t], {xC[t], yC[t]}][{xC[t] + L0/2, 
      yC[t] + L0/2}];
   {p4x, p4y} = 
    RotationTransform[angle[t], {xC[t], yC[t]}][{xC[t] - L0/2, 
      yC[t] - L0/2}];

   p21 = {p2x - p1x, p2y - p1y}; 
   p41 = {p4x - p1x, p4y - p1y};
   p = {xP[t] - p1x, yP[t] - p1y};

   p21Mag = Norm[p21]^2; 
   p41Mag = Norm[p41]^2; 

   If[0 <= p.p21 <= p21Mag && 0 <= p.p41 <= p41Mag,
      True,
      False
     ]
   ];

Manipulate[
 tick;     
 Grid[{{Row[{txt, " at time = ", t}]},
   {
    Graphics[
     {         
      {Blue, PointSize[.03], Point[{xP[t], yP[t]}]},
      {Opacity[.1], EdgeForm[Thick], White,
       Rotate[
        Rectangle[{xC[t] - L0/2, yC[t] - L0/2}, {xC[t] + L0/2, 
          yC[t] + L0/2}], angle[t]]}
      }
     ,
     PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 400]
    }}],

 Row[{Manipulator[Dynamic[t, {t = #;
       If[ isPointInside[t],
        txt = "Inside";           
        tick = Not[tick]
        ,
        txt = "COLLISION !!"
        ]} &], {0, 4, .001}], Dynamic[t]}],
 {{tick, False}, None},
 {{txt, "inside"}, None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {tick}
 ]
```

This is another simulation using faster rotation

[image]

Comment: Why not use dot products + short-circuit evaluation? `0 <= p.p21 <= p21Mag && 0 <= p.p41 <= p41Mag`

Comment: @J.M. thanks for suggestion. As I said in the question, I just translated the small code shown in [finding-whether-a-point-lies-inside-a-rectangle-or-not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752725/finding-whether-a-point-lies-inside-a-rectangle-or-not) and was not trying to change it at time as it was working. But I just edited it to use the dot.